# Deploying DB2 Warehouse to IBM Cloud with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, db2, ibm-cloud, dashdb, ibm-cloud-kubernetes

is there a way to deploy the docker image to our Kubernetes Cluster? 
I have been trying to add it with the below yaml file.
but when I run status it says the environment is not setup.

What I basically tried to do is to convert the docker run command into a kubectl deployment file:

```
docker run -d -it --privileged=true --net=host --name=Db2wh -v /mnt/clusterfs:/mnt/bludata0 -v /mnt/clusterfs:/mnt/blumeta0 store/ibmcorp/db2wh_ee:v2.10.0-db2wh-ppcle
```

Can you please help me?

```
#testreplicaset.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
labels:
run: db2whce
name: db2whce
spec:
# modify replicas according to your case
replicas: 1
selector:
matchLabels:
app: db2whce
template:
metadata:
labels:
app: db2whce
spec:
containers:
- name: db2whce
image: store/ibmcorp/db2wh_ee:v2.10.0-db2wh-linux
ports:
- containerPort: 8443
- containerPort: 389
- containerPort: 50022
- containerPort: 50001
- containerPort: 50000
- containerPort: 9929
- containerPort: 9300
- containerPort: 8998
- containerPort: 5000
- containerPort: 22
args:
- "--privileged=true"
- "--net=host"
- "--name=Db2wh"
- "-v /mnt/clusterfs:/mnt/bludata0"
- "-v /mnt/clusterfs:/mnt/blumeta0"
resources:
requests:
cpu: 3
memory: 14Gi
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /mnt/bludata0
name: db2wh-pvc
- mountPath: /mnt/clusterfs
name: db2wh-pvc
volumes:
- name: db2wh-pvc
persistentVolumeClaim:
claimName: db2wh-pvc
imagePullSecrets:
- name: dockerstore
```

Comment: Does the mounted file system exist? Any diagnostic logs?

Comment: provide logs you have